# How google check the apps submitted for publication in playstore?

Tags: google-play-store, google

I knew playstore authority ( None other than google)  take some time to analyze the app and then gives permission.Am I right? What do they do to analyze the app?
and how they check all assets( image or audio or video) are used without infringing copyright ?

Comment: I never heard that Google performs copyright checks. You as the developer are responsible for this. Only if you mimic an existing successful app Google may not publish an app as such mimic apps are usually spam or malicious apps.

Comment: As per [Play Console Help - Intellectual Property](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/9888072), Google rely on users' reports since they don't (and can't) check by themselves.

Comment: Thanks for comments.One more thing, If someone uses my artwork anywhere without my permission, how can I know that?(It's definitely not possible to check everything in internet)

Comment: You can't......